# How can I help Ubuntu as a developer?

Tags: python, java, php, development, community

I am intermediate Java/Python/PHP developer, but I really would like to help build something for Ubuntu for free. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very useful information in this regard on the Ubuntu App Showdown page:

[The Ubuntu App Showdown](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/)

The App Showdown should be closed already, but the information there is still useful. Basically, the quickest way to start is [Quickly](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/quickly-workflow/) and Python.

Answer (score 1):

The best part about it , there are so many ways to start . I will try an list some of them . So you can select the best to suite you.

Having an [**Launchpad account**](https://launchpad.net/+tour/index) paves the important way as being essential part . Through this you can answer and provide [solution to bugs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/HowToTriage) and many more things.

[**How can you Contribute to Ubuntu**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContributeToUbuntu) , Ubuntu wiki to introduce the Value of contribution.

[**How to Get Involved**](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/get-involved) , listing Various Groups and Parts of Ubuntu to Contribute with.

[**As a Application Developer**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment) , developing Apps through Quickly

[**Ubuntu Development Beginnings**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BeginnersTeam/FocusGroups/Development/Devbeginnings) , one of the best way . As an **opinion** , try to begin from here

---

Also it was already addressed here **Ask Ubuntu** site as following

[How can I contribute to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692/how-can-i-contribute-to-ubuntu)

[How to start contributing to Ubuntu development?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104075/how-to-start-contributing-to-ubuntu-development)

Further basic read on [How to Contribute to Open Source](http://www.wikihow.com/Contribute-to-Open-Source)